# AEM 6.2 cq:dialog Image upload preview not working

Tags: aem, aem-6

This is my first AEM project, I have a image upload in a component which is working, after uploading if i open settings of component to change the image, preview is not working as you can see in below picture.

[image]

**cq:dialog banner file upload properties** 
[image]

If i try to open image with `/content/xxxDetails/xxx/_jcr_content/par/banner/bannerImage` i can able to access image.

How do i fix the preview problem, I thing it's basic question but please help me  as this is my first project.

**EDIT: cq:dialog**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    jcr:title="Properties"
    sling:resourceType="cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog">
    <content
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
        <layout
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/tabs"
            type="nav"/>
        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
            <banner
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                jcr:title="Banner Properties"
                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/section">
                <layout
                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/fixedcolumns"/>
                <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                    <columns
                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
                        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                            <headerText
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/textfield"
                                fieldLabel="Heading Text"
                                name="./header"/>
                            <SubText
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/textarea"
                                fieldLabel="SubHeading"
                                name="./subtext"/>
                            <bannerImage
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/fileupload"
                                autoStart="{Boolean}false"
                                class="cq-droptarget"
                                fieldLabel="Banner"
                                fileNameParameter="./bannerImgName"
                                fileReferenceParameter="./bannerImgRef"
                                mimeTypes="[image]"
                                multiple="{Boolean}false"
                                name="./bannerImage"
                                title="Upload Image"
                                uploadUrl="${suffix.path}"
                                useHTML5="{Boolean}true"/>
                        </items>
                    </columns>
                </items>
            </banner>
        </items>
    </content>
</jcr:root>
```

Error Logs

```
09.05.2017 18:29:15.949 *ERROR* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1494334755944] POST /content/xxxDetails/xxx/_jcr_content/par/banner HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.servlets.post.impl.operations.ModifyOperation Exception during response processing.
org.apache.sling.api.resource.PersistenceException: Unable to commit changes to session.
    at org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.internal.helper.jcr.JcrResourceProvider.commit(JcrResourceProvider.java:482)
    at org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.providers.stateful.AuthenticatedResourceProvider.commit(AuthenticatedResourceProvider.java:215)
    at org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.helper.ResourceResolverControl.commit(ResourceResolverControl.java:411)
    at org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.ResourceResolverImpl.commit(ResourceResolverImpl.java:1224)
    at org.apache.sling.servlets.post.AbstractPostOperation.run(AbstractPostOperation.java:129)
    at org.apache.sling.servlets.post.impl.SlingPostServlet.doPost(SlingPostServlet.java:202)
    at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingAllMethodsServlet.mayService(SlingAllMethodsServlet.java:149)
    at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet.service(SlingSafeMethodsServlet.java:345)
    at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet.service(SlingSafeMethodsServlet.java:376)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.RequestData.service(RequestData.java:546)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.SlingComponentFilterChain.render(SlingComponentFilterChain.java:44)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:77)
    at com.day.cq.personalization.impl.TargetComponentFilter.doFilter(TargetComponentFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilterWithErrorHandling(WCMDebugFilter.java:187)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilter(WCMDebugFilter.java:154)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.filterRootInclude(WCMComponentFilter.java:362)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.doFilter(WCMComponentFilter.java:177)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processComponent(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:282)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.RequestSlingFilterChain.render(RequestSlingFilterChain.java:49)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:77)
    at com.adobe.cq.social.ugcbase.security.impl.SaferSlingPostServlet.doFilter(SaferSlingPostServlet.java:126)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.assetlinkshare.AdhocAssetShareAuthHandler.doFilter(AdhocAssetShareAuthHandler.java:381)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.servlet.ActivityRecordHandler.doFilter(ActivityRecordHandler.java:155)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:73)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:73)
    at com.adobe.granite.requests.logging.impl.RequestLoggerImpl.doFilter(RequestLoggerImpl.java:127)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.adobe.granite.csrf.impl.CSRFFilter.doFilter(CSRFFilter.java:220)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at org.apache.sling.security.impl.ContentDispositionFilter.doFilter(ContentDispositionFilter.java:181)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl.doFilter(AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl.java:367)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.warp.TimeWarpFilter.doFilter(TimeWarpFilter.java:106)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.mobile.core.impl.redirect.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:248)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.aem.community.core.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:50)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.debug.RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.doFilter(RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.java:95)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.day.cq.analytics.provisioning.impl.UserAuthenticationRequestFilter.doFilter(UserAuthenticationRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.adobe.cq.social.commons.cors.CORSAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(CORSAuthenticationFilter.java:91)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.impl.FormsHandlingServlet.doFilter(FormsHandlingServlet.java:285)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.adobe.granite.optout.impl.OptOutFilter.doFilter(OptOutFilter.java:74)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.adobe.cq.history.impl.HistoryRequestFilter.doFilter(HistoryRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMRequestFilter.doFilter(WCMRequestFilter.java:90)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.adobe.cq.mcm.campaign.servlets.CampaignCopyTracker.doFilter(CampaignCopyTracker.java:100)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterFilter.doFilter(RewriterFilter.java:83)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.adobe.granite.httpcache.impl.InnerCacheFilter.doFilter(InnerCacheFilter.java:77)
    at com.adobe.granite.httpcache.impl.InnerCacheFilter.doFilter(InnerCacheFilter.java:56)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:129)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.adobe.granite.rest.impl.servlet.ApiResourceFilter.doFilter(ApiResourceFilter.java:67)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at org.apache.sling.bgservlets.impl.BackgroundServletStarterFilter.doFilter(BackgroundServletStarterFilter.java:169)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.adobe.granite.resourceresolverhelper.impl.ResourceResolverHelperImpl.doFilter(ResourceResolverHelperImpl.java:84)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.doProcessRequest(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:151)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingMainServlet.service(SlingMainServlet.java:216)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:79)
    at com.adobe.granite.license.impl.LicenseCheckFilter.doFilter(LicenseCheckFilter.java:308)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:74)
    at org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter.internal.SslFilter.doFilter(SslFilter.java:89)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:74)
    at org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter.doFilter(ReferrerFilter.java:290)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:74)
    at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:129)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:74)
    at org.apache.sling.featureflags.impl.FeatureManager.doFilter(FeatureManager.java:116)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:74)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.log.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggerFilter.java:75)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:74)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:124)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:61)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.jcr.nodetype.ConstraintViolationException: OakConstraint0030: Uniqueness constraint violated at path [/] for one of the property in [jcr:uuid] having value 6483de35-5fc6-437e-a40d-c9a074ee96ad
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.api.CommitFailedException.asRepositoryException(CommitFailedException.java:225)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.api.CommitFailedException.asRepositoryException(CommitFailedException.java:212)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.delegate.SessionDelegate.newRepositoryException(SessionDelegate.java:670)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.delegate.SessionDelegate.save(SessionDelegate.java:496)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.SessionImpl$8.performVoid(SessionImpl.java:419)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.delegate.SessionDelegate.performVoid(SessionDelegate.java:274)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:416)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor45.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.sling.jcr.base.SessionProxyHandler$SessionProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(SessionProxyHandler.java:116)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.save(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.internal.helper.jcr.JcrResourceProvider.commit(JcrResourceProvider.java:480)
    ... 115 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.api.CommitFailedException: OakConstraint0030: Uniqueness constraint violated at path [/] for one of the property in [jcr:uuid] having value 6483de35-5fc6-437e-a40d-c9a074ee96ad
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.index.property.PropertyIndexEditor.checkUniquenessConstraints(PropertyIndexEditor.java:320)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.index.property.PropertyIndexEditor.updateIndex(PropertyIndexEditor.java:300)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.index.property.PropertyIndexEditor.leave(PropertyIndexEditor.java:243)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.index.IndexUpdate.leave(IndexUpdate.java:252)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.VisibleEditor.leave(VisibleEditor.java:63)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.CompositeEditor.leave(CompositeEditor.java:74)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.EditorDiff.process(EditorDiff.java:56)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.EditorHook.processCommit(EditorHook.java:54)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.CompositeHook.processCommit(CompositeHook.java:61)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.CompositeHook.processCommit(CompositeHook.java:61)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentNodeStore$Commit.prepare(SegmentNodeStore.java:488)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentNodeStore$Commit.optimisticMerge(SegmentNodeStore.java:519)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentNodeStore$Commit.execute(SegmentNodeStore.java:575)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentNodeStore.merge(SegmentNodeStore.java:238)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.state.ProxyNodeStore.merge(ProxyNodeStore.java:43)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.core.MutableRoot.commit(MutableRoot.java:247)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.delegate.SessionDelegate.commit(SessionDelegate.java:347)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.delegate.SessionDelegate.save(SessionDelegate.java:494)
    ... 124 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Do you see any 404/403 errors in the network tab of your browser when you are in the preview dialog?

Comment: @i.net yes GET http://localhost:4502/content/xxxDetails/xxx/_jcr_content/par/banner.img.png?:ck=1493983713311 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Can you try opening that link in a browser and see why you are getting 404? Maybe some path is wrong or protocol is blocked?

Comment: @i.net yes i tried many times. "/_jcr_content/par/banner.img.png" is the URL preview window using... but  "/_jcr_content/par/banner/bannerImage" is only working

Comment: Can you share your `cq:dialog` node please?

Comment: @Viswa `fileupload` looks fine and it should work. Have you tried to put this control on a new tab? Could be an AEM bug.

Comment: @AbdulMunim what do you mean by "put this control on a new tab" ?

Comment: @Viswa I see you've already created a tab "Banner Properties" using `granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/fixedcolumns` layout. Try putting the `fileupload` control something similar to Banner tab i.e. "Banner Image".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be facing this issue when uploading the file from local disk instead of referencing it from DAM. The reason being, when the file is uploaded it is created as a `nt:file` under your components node with the name `bannerImage` (the name property provided in the dialog). Whereas, AEM is expecting with the name `file`.

If quick fix is what you need, change your name for bannerImage as shown below. Also ensure your component inherits from `foundation/components/parbase` so that the `img` selector is handled by the servlet.

```
<bannerImage
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"                          
    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/fileupload"
    autoStart="{Boolean}false"
    class="cq-droptarget"
    fieldLabel="Banner"
    fileNameParameter="./bannerImgName"
    fileReferenceParameter="./bannerImgRef"
    mimeTypes="[image]"
    multiple="{Boolean}false"
    name="./file"
    title="Upload Image"
    uploadUrl="${suffix.path}"
    useHTML5="{Boolean}true"/>
```

But it is best if the image is allowed to be created as a child of the current component (example can be found at `wcm/foundation/components/textimage`). Inorder to achieve that, you can change the bannerImage configuration as shown below, and additionally add a hidden field to set the sling:resourceType for the image node.

```
<bannerImage
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"                          
        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/fileupload"
        autoStart="{Boolean}false"
        class="cq-droptarget"
        fieldLabel="Banner"
        fileNameParameter="./image/bannerImgName"
        fileReferenceParameter="./image/bannerImgRef"
        mimeTypes="[image]"
        multiple="{Boolean}false"
        name="./image/file"
        title="Upload Image"
        uploadUrl="${suffix.path}"
        useHTML5="{Boolean}true"/>
<headerText
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/hidden"
        name="./image/sling:resourceType"
        value="wcm/foundation/components/image"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for solution, second solution works (hidden field solution). But can't understand how this works. i already tried first solution it's not working (Don't know why, can you help me with this ?).

Comment: The first one works for me. Does your component inherit from `foundation/components/parbase` ?

Comment: Yes, from `wcm/foundation/components/parbase`

Comment: I guess there is no `wcm/foundation/components/parbase`. Can you change it to `foundation/components/parbase`?

Comment: getting `org.apache.sling.api.SlingException: Exception during response processing.` while settings image in touch UI

Comment: @Viswa please check the logs and add a bit more info about the error

Comment: from the web page and chrome dev console that's all i am getting.. if you don't mind where can i find logs of AEM ? i am new to AEM.

Comment: You have to check the installation folder/crx-quickstart/logs/error.log

Comment: Looks like a different issue altogether. The uuid of the node appears to conflict with some other node. Can u delete the component on the page and reauthor it again and check. Much better if you can also logout and relogin and then add the component on the page.

Comment: how to referencing it from DAM ?